# customize windows 7 progressbars

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

How do I customize the progress bars in windows 7. Is there any SOFTWARE that can do this.
Something that could change the color, or the kind of animation that it is making.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the Task Bar Color in Windows 7 in [this way](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/6838-Want-to-have-Blue-progressbars-in-Windows-7-.Look-no-further).

[image]

and you should try [Windows Blind](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) for more customization.

Comment: Can you add the relevant details of the first link to your answer? As it stands you have to login to that forum to see the details, so it's not the best way of laying out the steps to change the task bar color.